# In swagger, is there a recommended way to document a number field with a length limit?

Tags: swagger, api-design

We have some numeric fields, that for legacy reasons have implicit length limits.

Given a number field with a length limit of 5, the obvious route is to set the max to 99999, but then is there any way to specify that 1.111 is ok, and 1.1111 is not, in the swagger spec?

For example:

```
numberField:
  type: number
  format: float
  minimum: 0
  maximum: 99999
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use the property `maxLength`

```
 numberField:
   type: number
   format: float
   maxLength: 5
```

Comment: The spec says that "maxLength" follows the JSON schema specs, which indicate this is only valid for string type fields. I do see that the Swagger UI displays maxLength for numbers, though the tool we are using does not (ReDoc). It seems that it isn't clear this is supported for numbers.

Comment: I checked that in editor.swagger.io and it works, so maybe it ia working for numbers too